# how to Automatic OTP Retrieval (Autofill) using Jetpack Compose Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack

I want to Retrieve SMS OTP or autofill OTP from the SMS automatically, can anybody please help to work in the jetpack compose android. automatic boxes will be filled or the user will enter it manually.

Comment: Please provide more detail. There is a sms retriever api for that: https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview
Do you have any specific problem connecting that to your jetpack compose UI? What did you try, why did it fail?